# Configuring simple web application with JOSSO

Tags: josso

I am new to JOSSO and want to implement Single Sign On on my simple web application (JSP/Servlet). I have successfully installed the JOSSO by following the steps given under link - http://www.josso.org/confluence/display/JOSSO1/Quick+Start#QuickStart-Prerequisites .Upon running link http:/ /localhost:8080/partnerapp. I did got the login screen but a different one from wat is mentioned in the above link. I did not get the fields for username & password but the message "You're an anonymous user." with login button.

Can anyone please help me out in setting up JOSSO (if anything is missing) and configure my web application. Please as I am new to JOSSO.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The anonymus user page shows that you have setup properly. Now try creating a simple helloworld application and try making it a partner app. Try running it.

Follow the instructions in these links :
[Setup Java Application Using Josso](http://www.josso.org/confluence/display/JOSSO1/Jossify+your+JEE+Application)

[Setup Tomcat for Josso](http://www.josso.org/confluence/display/JOSSO1/Jossify+your+Application+for+Tomcat+-+Quick+Start)